# Cleaner way to detect change and keyup, eg in a single line?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with text fields, text areas and checkboxes.  At the moment, to enable/disable submit, i'm doing this:

```
$("form").change(function(){toggleSubmit()});
$("form").keyup(function(){toggleSubmit()});
```

Is there a way to do this in a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('form').change(toggleSubmit).keyup(toggleSubmit);
```

Or:

```
$('form').bind('change keyup', toggleSubmit);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('form').bind('change keyup', function(){toggleSubmit();});
```

[jQuery .bind() Multiple Events](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#multiple-events)

**UPDATE:** Of course you can simply write `toggleSubmit` instead of `function(){toggleSubmit();}`, I just left your original example there (you might have wanted to add some other things, I don't know).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure jQuery allows you to concatenate them, but I would not call it cleaner. Shorter isn't always cleaner, and this is pretty straightforward.

If you want to, you can do this:

```
 $("form").change(function(){toggleSubmit()}).keyup(...etc..);
```

But i'd call it less clear.